# Make two divs in different column same height depending on content

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have two [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) columns which have two divs, and each div has text inside. Both texts don't have the same length, which is why, the divs are not always the same height (depending on the media query)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-10 columns">
    <p>Some text here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="medium-10 columns>
    <p>A lot more text in here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

what I want to do is, that both divs are always the same height (according to the div with most text in it). Also I want to center the text within the div which is less text. I always used to do this with, Flexbox. But it crashes because of the Foundation grid layout. Any idea?

CSS only!

Comment: Try jQuery matchHeight: http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: I used your exact same question's title, typed it into Google, and found a million different methods of achieving your goal. If your problem is different, please explain.

Comment: no javascript! Only CSS

Answer (score 1):

You can always use display: table on your .row class, and display: table-cell on your columns. Table cell will force the two divs to be the same height, no matter the content.

Answer (score 0):

From the foundation doc:

> You can create an equal height container using a few data attributes.
>   Apply the data-equalizer attribute to a parent container. Then apply
>   the data-equalizer-watch attribute to each element you'd like to have
>   an equal height. The height of data-equalizer-watch attribute will be
>   equal to that of the tallest element.

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
  <div class="large-6 columns panel" data-equalizer-watch>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns panel" data-equalizer-watch>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

[Foundation Doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html)